# How to handle concurrency when Creating an Queue with SQL table as backend

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I want to create a simple queue with a sql database as backend.
the table have the fields, id, taskname,runat(datetime) and hidden(datetime).

I want to ensure a queue item is not run once and only once.

The idea is when a client want to dequeue, a stored procedure selects the first item(sorted by runat  and hidden < now), sets the hidden field to current time + 2min and returns the item.

How does MS Sql (Azure to be precise) wokr, will two clients be able to run at the same time and both set the same item to hidden and return it? Or can i be sure that they are run one by one and the second one will not return the same item as the hidden field was changed with the first?

Comment: Service Broker would be a better way to do this.

Comment: It have some disadvantages: Fixed structure. Service Broker Queues have a specific table structure that cannot be altered in any fashion. among some others. I would like to have my own table that i can maintain.

Comment: That's not relevant.  You are assuming that a single structure is the best solution, but that's unlikely to be the case.

Comment: What's the relative priority of the hidden(datetime) vs. the runat(datetime). IE., what happens if runat=NOW, but Hidden is in the furture

Comment: Oops, never mind about hidden vs runat, I misread it.

Comment: hidden is just a method for hide the task for a few minutes, if the task handler fails at running the task it will show up again a few mins later. I also added a dequeue counter, in case the same task failed 5 times it can be reported as corrupt. But reading abit more, it seems that i can do some concurrency with the output statement.

Comment: Service Broker isn't available with SQL Azure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to get a lock (Row or table) on the queue item you are receiving.  You can use a couple of ways, my favorite being the UPDATE with OUTPUT clause.  Either will produce serialized access to the table.

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetNextItem_output
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN

    UPDATE TOP(1) Messages
    SET [Status] = 1
    OUTPUT INSERTED.MessageID, INSERTED.Data
    WHERE [Status] = 0

    COMMIT TRAN
END

CREATE PROCEDURE spGetNextItem_tablockx
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN

    DECLARE @MessageID int, @data xml

    SELECT TOP(1) @MessageID = MessageID, @Data = Data
    FROM Messages WITH (ROWLOCK, XLOCK, READPAST) --lock the row, skip other locked rows
    WHERE [Status] = 0

    UPDATE Messages
    SET [Status] = 1
    WHERE MessageID = @MessageID

    SELECT @MessageID AS MessageID, @Data as Data

    COMMIT TRAN
END
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Messages](
    [MessageID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Data] [xml] NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Messages] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [MessageID] ASC
    )
)
```

Comment: looks like what i have come up with my self also. I found with (rowlock, readpast) online, not sure what the meaning/differences for this and tablockx

Comment: I don't know if ROWLOCK and READPAST alone would suffice.  ROWLOCK causes a read lock to be taken on the row in question, while READPAST will skip any locked rows.  On the surface, they seem to offer exclusive access to a single row, but another non-hinted query could mess that up.  I would modify WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST) to include UPDLOCK or XLOCK to ensure that no writes take place between the select and the update.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx for descriptions of lock hints.

Comment: @usr, I agree.  In high use tables, TABLOCKX would produce uneccessary contention.  The example code was taken from a low use table, and I was not concerned with the overall throughput.  I have since updated it to use row level locks.

Comment: Does the lock exist until the stored procedure terminate ? Then rowlock should be fine for my case. it ensures that no other clients calling the procedure will get the same elements as they cant read the rows and will just skip em because of readpast. Correct?

Comment: @Mitch I appreciate the update! You did the right thing. I really dislike bad sample code publicly visible on the web. You earned your +1!

Comment: @s093294, the lock is held in the context of the transaction.  I have included explicit BEGIN TRAN and END TRAN statements for my scope, but barring that, the lock would have been held for the duration of the batch.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175523(v=sql.105).aspx .  Without XLOCK, you should be fine so long as only the one statement with ROWLOCK is being executed is being run, I don't see a problem.  That being said, give in to paranoia and add the XLOCK just in case.  That protects against some agent in the future doing something you didn't expect and breaking your code.

Comment: I did this: set nocount on;
  with cte as (
    select top(@Batch) *
      from CrawlTaskItems with (rowlock, readpast) where RunAt <= GETUTCDATE() AND HiddenUntil <= GETUTCDATE()
    order by RunAt )
  update cte SET DequeueCount = DequeueCount + 1, HiddenUntil = DATEADD(n,2,GETUTCDATE() )
    output inserted.*

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure SQL Database is going to behave just like a SQL Server database in terms of concurrency. This is a database problem, not a Windows Azure problem.

Now: If you went with Windows Azure Queues (or Service Bus Queues) rather than implementing your own, then the behavior is well documented. For instance: with Azure Queues, first-in gets the queue item, and then the item is marked as *invisible* until it's either deleted or a timeout period has been reached.

Comment: A Sql Queue is cost-free compared to azure queues transaction cost :) The question asked was how the database is behaving - ergo for a solution to the "database problem" you call it. But i found something on google mentioned thati can use with(rowlock,readpast) in my statements.

Comment: Queue transactions: 100,000 for a penny. Just how many transactions are you generating??? 100 queue operations / second, sustained, over a month, would run $26. Plus, you don't need to poll in a tight loop. And you can read up to 32 messages at once (consuming just 1 transaction). And you can format queue messages to be multi-message with delimiters (further reducing transactions). And barely any storage cost due to the fact your queue length would be relatively small.